# How to drop specific column and then select all columns from spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scenario here - Have 30 columns in one dataframe, need to drop specific column and select remaining columns and put it to another dataframe. How can I achieve this? I tried below.

```
val df1: DataFrame = df2.as(a).join( df3.as(b),col(a.key) === col(b.key), inner).drop(a.col1)
.select(" a.star ")
```

when I do show of df1, its still show col1. Any advise on resolving this.

Comment: What are the columns in dataframe a and b?

Comment: dataframe a has 30 columns (1 to 30) and b has 1 column and need to select 29 columns from a except 1 or any column. Sorry, if I am unclear from above post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really just seems like you need to use a "left_semi" join.

```scala
val df1 = df2.drop('col1).join(df3, df2("key") === df3("key"), "left_semi")
```

If `key` is an actual column you can simplify the syntax even further

```scala
val df1 = df2.drop('col1).join(df3, Seq("key"), "left_semi")
```

The best syntax depends on the details of what your real data looks like. If you need to refer to col1 in `df2` specifically because there's ambiguity, then use `df2("col1")`

`left_semi` joins take all the columns from the left table for rows finding a match in the right table.

Comment: Thanks mck & kanielc for advise and approaches, I achieved this like below. val df1: DataFrame = df2.as(a).join( df3.as(b),col(a.key) === col(b.key), inner)
.select(col(" a.* ")).drop(col(a.col1)). This gives result all columns of df2 except col1 (droped col1)

Answer (score 1):

`drop` requires a string without table alias, so you can try:

```
val df1 = df2.as("a")
    .join(df3.as("b"), col("a.key") === col("b.key"), "inner")
    .drop("col1")
    .select("a.*")
```

Or instead of dropping the column, you can filter the columns to be selected:

```
val df1 = df2.as("a")
    .join(df3.as("b"), col("a.key") === col("b.key"), "inner")
    .select(df2.columns.filterNot(_ == "col1").map("a." + _): _*)
```